# Add bson tags to the go struct using GoModifyTags

Tags: json, go, visual-studio-code, bson, go-structtag

I am trying to use [GoModifyTags](https://github.com/fatih/gomodifytags) but it's not giving me required result.
I have installed this as per the instruction but don't know how to implement. Using VScode editor.

I am trying to add bson tags in my file.

Currently, I have:

```
type option []struct {
    Option  string  `json:"option"`
    ID      float64 `json:"id"`
    Correct bool    `json:"correct"`
}
```

Required:

```
type option []struct {
    Option  string  `json:"option" bson:"option"`
    ID      float64 `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Correct bool    `json:"correct" bson:"correct"`
}
```

How can I achieve this?

### Solution:

Following the instruction of **Jihoon Ye**, I am able to get my required result. Here are steps for VSCode with pictures to help you understand better.

1. Go to File -> Preference -> Settings
2. You must have GO extension installed on your VSCode
   [image]
3. Type **"Go: Add Tags"** in the search box and you will see the settings as below. Add bson in the tag field.
   [image]
4. Select your go struct in the code
5. Right-click the selected code **OR** use command palette (use shortcut cntrl + shift + p) and select **"Go: Add tags to struct fields"**
   [image]
6. Here is the final result
   [image]

Peace,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using the command

install GoModifyTags.

```
$ go get github.com/fatih/gomodifytags
```

Enter the command below.

```
$ gomodifytags -file main.go -struct option -add-tags bson -w
```

The results below will then be printed out.

```golang
type option []struct {
    Option  string  `json:"option" bson:"option"`
    ID      float64 `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Correct bool    `json:"correct" bson:"correct"`
}
```

### Using the VSCode

In user settings, setting "Go: Add Tags" as below.
[image]

Place the cursor in the structure and run "Go: Add Tags To Struct Field".

Comment: Thanks Jihoon. I tried this on my terminal after installation `$ gomodifytags -file main.go -struct option -add-tags bson -w` but it's unable to recognize. How can I do with command line ?
I was able to successfully **produce bson and json tags** in my struct using your VSCode instruction you provided. Thanks.

Comment: When you type a command on the command line, what message is displayed?